# NetBeans generated Makefile ignores test return codes

Tags: c++, testing, netbeans, makefile, automated-tests

I have a C++ project in NetBeans using generated Makefiles.  I set up a job in Jenkins (continuous integration server) to run the tests configured in NetBeans.  Now Jenkins runs the tests and captures their output, but it considers the build successful even when a test fails.

I'm using the Boost Unit Test Framework which of course returns a non-zero code on failure as any proper *nix program would.  So I wondered why Jenkins didn't understand when a test failed.  Then I found this in the generated Makefile-Debug.mk from NetBeans:

```
# Run Test Targets
.test-conf:
    @if [ "${TEST}" = "" ]; \
    then  \
        ${TESTDIR}/TestFiles/f1 || true; \
        ${TESTDIR}/TestFiles/f2 || true; \
    else  \
        ./${TEST} || true; \
    fi
```

So it seems like they deliberately ignore the return value of all tests.  But this doesn't make sense, because then what are your tests testing?

I tried to find a setting in NetBeans to say "Let failing tests break the build" but didn't find anything.  I also tried to find a bug in the NetBeans tracker for this but didn't see any in my brief search.

Is there any other reasonable solution?  I want Jenkins to fail my build if any test fails.  Right now it only fails if a test fails to *build*, but if it builds and fails to *run*, success is reported.

Comment: I don't see this piece of code in the NetBeans-generated `nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk`. There is nothing about testing in this file on my system. How did you get this testing rule? (I'm on the NetBeans 8.0 without Java EE and servers - may be that's the reason?)

Comment: I'm using NetBeans 8.0 for C++.  I tested just now by creating a New C++ Application, then adding a New C++ Simple Test.  I replaced `return (EXIT_SUCCESS);` at the bottom of the test main() with `throw;`.  When I run the test, NetBeans reports it as successful (!) despite that main() returns non-zero and stderr displays `Aborted (core dumped)`.  Apparently NetBeans test result reporting works by grepping for magic strings in stdout like `%TEST_FAILED%` (which is shown in the default generated C++ Simple Test code), and ignores return values.  This is shocking.

Comment: It looks like this "Simple Test" is only a template, not a real thing. I've found rather long tutorial page for you: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/c-unit-test.html. They say you'll need to add the "CUnit" testing framework. Still not a word about Jenkins...

Comment: "CppUnit" for C++ also... However I didn't do that myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that NetBeans (up to version 8 at least) cannot support this.  What I did to work around it is to do `make build-tests` rather than `make test` in Jenkins, followed by a loop over all the generated test files (`TestFiles/f*` in the build directory) to run them.

This is a major shortcoming in NetBeans' Makefile generator, as it is fundamentally incompatible with running tests outside of NetBeans itself.  Thanks to @HEKTO for the link which led me to this page about writing NetBeans testing plugins: http://wiki.netbeans.org/CND69UnitTestsPluginTutotial

What that page tells you is basically that NetBeans relies on parsing the textual output of tests to determine success or failure.  What it doesn't tell you is that NetBeans generates defective Makefiles which ignore critical failures in tests, including aborts, segmentation faults, assertion failures, uncaught exceptions, etc.  It assumes you will use a test framework that it knows about (which is only CppUnit), or manually write magic strings at the right moments in your test programs.

I thought about taking the time to write a NetBeans unit test plugin for the Boost Unit Test Framework, but it won't help Jenkins at all: the plugins are only used when tests are run inside NetBeans itself, to display pretty status indicators.